# docker-compose postgres and nodejs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to create a *docker-compose* that launches 2 containers: one my *NodeJS* API and the other a *Postgresql DB*. But **I don't want the database to be accessible through the internet but only the API** because only the API should contact it and no one else.
I created a network and didn't publish the DB port (5432) but when I try to run my docker-compose I get an error which I don't understand.

Here is the error during *docker-compose up* :
[image]

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:16.15.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3001
CMD npm start
```

And my docker-compose :

```
version: "3"

services:
    api_nodejs:
        build: .
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - ${APP_PORT}:3001
        command: npm start
        volumes:
            - .:/app/
            - /app/node_modules
        networks:
            my_network:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.0.1

    db:
        image: postgres:14.3
        restart: always
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
            - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        networks:
            my_network:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.0.2

networks:
    my_network:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
```

Comment: You seem to have attached an image file to your question in place of the error text.  Can you [edit] the question to include the actual text of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Error "Address already in use"

you give your container api_nodejs the IP 192.168.0.1, this IP is mostly used by your router.